# IIS 10.0, What does config source -1: and 0: mean here?

Tags: c#, iis

This is the error I am getting when I try to browse the website from IIS. I have been trying different solutions that errors related to this one were solved with, but I've had no luck. I have no idea what the config source means here.

[image]

Comment: The -1 and 0 aren't really important here. The problem is that it's having trouble reading your web.config file. Have you made any modifications to your web.config recently?

Comment: The more helpful hints on your error page are the first and scond line and, in this case,  'Config File' under 'Detailed Error Information'. Before trying to figure out error codes, read the rest of the error message :)

Comment: Simply search for "500.19" "0x8007000d" and you can find tons of useful posts on what the issue can be. The line number is only helpful when it points to a actual line inside your config file.

Answer (score 3):

The -1 means what the description says

> Config Source: -1: not able to read the config source

This could mean:

1. Malformatted web.config (check for correctness with an xml checker)
2. Missing addons. It's a known problem when you have url rewrite sections and you have not installed it on IIS
3. Missing access to read the config file (highly unlikely)

We can help you more if you share the config with obfuscated values where they are confidential.

Comment: adding number 4. If the app is .net core then you need to install Windows Hosting Bundle - Microsoft .NET windows server hosting